# For $0 < x < y \leq \frac{\pi}{2}$, prove that $\frac xy < \frac {\sin x}{\sin y} < \frac{\pi}{2y}$

Tags: derivatives

For $$0 < x < y \leq \frac{\pi}{2}$$ prove that $$\frac xy < \frac {\sin x}{\sin y} < \frac{\pi}{2y}$$

I am studying for my finals and I cant seem to solve this one. Since the chapter which contains this exercise is about finding monotonicity from derivatives, I will probably have to set $f(x) = ...$ and then derive it to prove it's greater than 0, maybe $f(x) = \frac{x}{\cos x}$ but I don't know what to do next. I cant really understand the $y$ at $\frac{\pi}{2y}$, since $f\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right) = \frac{\pi}{2}$. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{x}{y} < \frac{\sin x}{\sin y} \Leftrightarrow \frac{\sin y}{y} < \frac{\sin x}{x}$$

which makes sense because $x < y$. (Think about the unit circle: $x$ is the length of the arc while $\sin x$ is the length of the vertical; their ratio becomes smaller as $x$ becomes larger.)

$$\frac{\sin x}{\sin y} < \frac{\pi}{2y} \Leftrightarrow \sin x < \pi / 2 \frac{\sin y}{y}$$

$\frac{\sin y}{y}$ is smallest when $y = \pi/2$ by the same argument as above, and this gives $\sin x < 1$, which is true since $0<x < \pi/2$.

If you want to formalize the argument, consider the derivative of $f(x) = \frac{\sin x}{x}$ on $(0, \pi/2)$.

$\frac{\partial}{\partial x} \left( \frac{\sin x}{x} \right) = \frac{x \cos x - \sin x}{x^2}$. Claim: this derivative is $< 0$ on $(0, \pi/2)$. $x \cos x < \sin x \Rightarrow x < \tan x$. There is a neat geometric proof of this last fact, but since you are studying derivatives, here is a straightforward way to prove that: at $x=0$, we have $x = \tan x$. For $0 < x< \pi/2$, compare their derivatives: we have $1 < \frac{1}{\cos^2 x}$ since $\cos^2 x \in (0,1)$. Thus $\tan x > x$ on this interval.

Comment: I had kinda thought f doing it this way but since I am on a chapter which involves derivatives and monotonicity. I am not sure, it may be just a dumb exercise.

Comment: @alexk745 See my (edited) last sentence. That's probably what your exercise wants you to do.

Comment: Yeah, you are right. Thanks for the help! (Dumb me, it was kinda obvious but I was working it for like half an hour....)

Comment: @alexk745 No problem! I've updated the answer with the derivative approach your textbook might have been expecting.

Comment: using the unit circle  seems intuitive, but not very rigorous, to see that $\frac{\sin t  }{t}$ is decreasing  without the use of derivative. i will be happy to see a proof that does not use derivative at all.